# insert response from axios.post into state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I use axios to connect to my api and get a bunch of graphic files for ships.  Like this:

```
axios.get(`/api/serveEnemyShips/graphics-files/${shipId}/files`)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ files: response.data })
  })
```

This works and sets the state for files.

What would be the best way of adding to this state if a user wanted to upload a custom graphic?

I initially just used axios.post to upload the ship graphic, then performed another axios.get against my api, but that seems expensive.

I was hoping I could just upload the graphic, and then insert that response data(from the axios post) into my state and not have to do another axios.get after the upload.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last paragraph sounds reasonable. Granted that you get the newly created graphic in response to the post request, you could just add it to your array in state. If you don't get the data in the response, you most likely have all the data locally already, which you can use.

**Example**

```
axios.post(`/api/serveEnemyShips/graphics-files/${shipId}/files`, newFile)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { files: [...previousState.files, response.data] };
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks, do I need to define previousState somehow before the axios.post? Like this: "var previousState = this.state"  Also, what does the return do?  Does it return a new array of files or a new state with files?  thanks again

Comment: [`setState` can take a function as argument](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) which I'm doing above, and the first argument to that function is the previous state. It's a good practice to use the function variation of `setState` when you are updating your state that *depends on the previous state*.

Comment: I think I get it.  But I still need to do something like " const previousState = this.state ", correct?  thanks

Comment: You don't need to. It might look a bit more clear with this syntax: `this.setState(function (previousState) { ... })`. React calls the function and we name the first argument `previousState`.